# Comprehensive list of date format patterns in obj-c for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

Is there an actual, comprehensive list of supported date format patterns/tokens?  I've been looking at the [API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter), and they mention a few of them, such as `MM`, but where's the rest?

Comment: From the NSDateFormatter doc click on the link to "Data Formatting Guide", then "Date Formatters", then, a couple of paragraphs down, find the list of formatter versions.  Generally you want to select "version tr35-25", unless you're targeting iOS 5.

Comment: It's so deep in the navigation to find, though it is inevitable! http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Comprehensive list found here http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apple imports the Unicode standard so the appendix that summarises date format fields is [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 13):

If you follow the links to the "[Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)", you will see this information:

> The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical
>   Standard #35. The version of the standard varies with release of the
>   operating system:
>
> - Formatters in iOS 5.0-5.1 use version [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - Formatters in iOS 4.0-4.2 use version [tr35-15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-15.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - Formatters in iOS 3.2 use version [tr35-12](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-12.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0 use version [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - Formatters in OS X v10.7 and iOS 4.3 use version [tr35-17](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - Formatters in OS X v10.6 and iOS 3.0-3.1 use version [tr35-10](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Yes, that is the complete information.  Apple does make it a little hard to dig out -- a couple of levels of indirection from NSDateFormatter html.